# Vs2015 C# wpf can not reference control name after add a new control

Tags: asp.net, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I am writing WPF using C# in VS2015.When I dragged a control, for example a textbox, to the disign view,and double click the textbox to create a event handle function,after that I try to reference this textbox by its name "textBox",but it said "the name 'textBox' does not exist in the current context".I can't fix this error unless I close the solution and reopen it(yes,when I reopen the solution,it can correctly reference the control).

And I have a try to reset environment settings,it doesn't help.

Comment: Did you used x:name or name attribute in Xaml to refer the control in your event handler?

Comment: @Joseph Did you mean wheather I type the right name?I think it is right.When I drag a textbox in design view,vs2015 generate the code     `<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="50,542,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>`,And I use 'textBox1' to refer it,like `textBox1.Text = "something";`,and it raise the error,actually,in intellisense,there is not the 'textBox1' existence.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that the reason is I work on a virtual system,and my solution is biuld in share folder with host computer.I change the directory to a virtual system's folder,it work correctly.